# Can virtual network be in different Resource Group while creating a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-group

I want to create the virtual machine on VM in `ABC` resource group from `Image1` which is also in `ABC` resource group using powershell.

Now The problem I'm facing is that the virtual network is in different Resource Group say `XYZ`.So I have tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)    
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "ABC" `
    -Name "VName" `
    -ImageName "Image1" `
    -Location "West US" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "XYZ\Vnetname" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -Credential $psCred `
    -OpenPorts 3389
```

I have searched on this, but there are answers if you are using Angular CLI or creating a VM from templates. But I want to write in powershell without templates.

### Edit

I have tried this, but no able to proceed further

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
$ResourceGroupName = "ABC"
$VMSize = "Standard_B2s"
$VMName = "VName1"
$LocationName = "West US"
$NICName = "VName123"
$VirtualNetworkName = "VNetName"
$VirtualNetworkResourceGroup = "XYZ"
$VnetAddressPrefix = "10.3.5.0/25"
$SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.3.5.0/25"
$SubnetName = "Subnet1"

$SingleSubnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix $SubnetAddressPrefix
$Vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VirtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $VirtualNetworkResourceGroup -Location $LocationName -AddressPrefix $VnetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SingleSubnet
$NIC = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName $VirtualNetworkResourceGroup -Location $LocationName -SubnetId $Vnet.Subnets[0].Id

$VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName $VMName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $NIC.Id

New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
```

$VnetAddressPrefix = "10.3.5.0/25" and $SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.3.5.0/25" --> was not sure what to enter. So from the Azure portal, I have checked the Subnet1's AddressRange, and put that same value.

When I run this command, it shows the below error.

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:17 char:1
+ $NIC = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NICName -ResourceGroupName  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

WARNING: New-AzureRmVMConfig: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The StorageAccountType property for a DataDisk will return
Standard_LRS and Premium_LRS
WARNING: Set-AzureRmVMOperationSystem: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The StorageAccountType property for a DataDisk will return
Standard_LRS and Premium_LRS
Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Id'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:21 char:73
+ ... chine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $NIC.Id
+                                                                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.AddAzureVMNetworkInterfaceCommand

WARNING: New-AzureRmVM: A property of the output of this cmdlet will change in an upcoming breaking change release. The StorageAccountType property for a DataDisk will return Standard_LRS and
 Premium_LRS
WARNING: Error occurred when choosing existing standard storage account for boot diagnostics: Sequence contains no matching element
WARNING: Since the VM is created using premium storage, new standard storage account, corpcpscps082813020, is created for boot diagnostics.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "New" on target "Vname1".
New-AzureRmVM : Required parameter 'networkProfile' is missing (null).
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Required parameter 'networkProfile' is missing (null).
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : b1d281a7-a1df-48f6-9983-67319267f11d
At line:23 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Locati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Vnet in the different resource group. But the limitation is your Vnet and VM must be in the same region.

**Update**

Use the PowerShell cmdlet to create a VM using the Vnet in another resource group,  you can reference the steps below.

1. Get the Vnet in another resource group using the command `Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName vnetResourceGroupName -Name VnetName`.
2. Create a network interface associated with the Vnet.
3. Set other options as usuall.
4. Create the VM.

The script below is just for reference.

```
$UserName = userName
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString password -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)

    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name resourceGroupName -Location location

    $PIP = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name publicIPName -DomainNameLabel publicIPDomain -ResourceGroupName resourceGroupName -Location location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
    $Vnet = $(Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName vnetResourceGroupName -Name VnetName)
    $NIC = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name NICNName -ResourceGroupName resourceGroupName -Location location -SubnetId $Vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PIP.Id

    $VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName vmName -VMSize vmSize
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName conputerName -Credential $psCred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
    $VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $NIC.Id

    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2012-R2-Datacenter' -Version latest
    New-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName resourceGroupName -Location location -VM $VirtualMachine
```

Comment: Yes, Vnet and VM Image are in the same location. Can you tell me what will be the command for that?

Comment: @CrazyCoder You can try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/new-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.7.0#examples). It will create a network interface and associate the nic with the subnet in another resource group and set the vm config.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the method mentioned in the link. I have updated the question based on the trials I have done. Something is not right in my cmdlet. Can you please have a look. I know I'm asking for more, but I really need to solve this.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Actually, you just to create a public IP and a network interface associated with the subnet in another resource group.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I update the answer, you can take a try.

Comment: If I do not want public IP for the VM, can I remove this parameter -->   -PublicIpAddressId $PIP.Id

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, you can try it. I succeeded in creating the nic without a public IP. But I do not try it until the end of creating the vm.